# ¿Cómo evitar que cualquier mensaje haga interferencia?

Tags: discord.js

Estoy intentando hacer una función con mi bot para jugar a "Simón Dice", funciona bien el código, pero el problema es que con cualquier mensaje que mande cualquier usuario, el bot responde como si hubieran usado el 'comando' para jugar. ¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Tengo otros comandos que funcionan de la misma manera y no hacen interferencia con otros mensajes. ¿Será que al ser un envío de mensajes random necesita programarse su propio comando como tal?

Este es mi código:

```
 if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.content == 'k!dice')
      message.delete()
   function randomnumb() {
    var rand = ["Toca pasto.", "Pinguea a Krauser.", "Compra juegos en Steam.", "Invita los tacos al pastor.", "Menciona un libro que haya marcado tu vida. *La Biblia no cuenta, pinche Peña Nieto.*", "Muestra tu librería de Steam.", "Muestra tus mejores stats en cualquier juego.", "Escribe tu username de Discord utilizando solamente tu codo: *Puede ser cualquiera de los dos o la extremidad de tu cuerpo que quieras.*"];

    return rand[Math.floor(Math.random() * rand.length)];
  }
  
  message.channel.send(randomnumb());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

utiliza `===` (estrictamente igual) en lugar de `==` (parecido o semejante) en este fragmento de codigo.

```
if (message.content == 'k!dice') // ❌
if (message.content === 'k!dice') // ✅
```

Espero haber ayudado.